# Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4)

Tags: java, apache-spark, quarkus, antlr4, apache-iceberg

I have a simple application using Java 11 and quarkus 3.2.10.Final.

Other dependencies are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
            <artifactId>iceberg-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
            <artifactId>iceberg-spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.iceberg</groupId>
            <artifactId>iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run my Main class which is simple Spark/Iceberg example, I see this:

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.9.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.10.1
ANTLR Runtime version 4.9.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.10.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractParser.parse(parsers.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseMultipartIdentifier(AbstractSqlParser.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute$.apply(unresolved.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.VirtualColumn$.<clinit>(namedExpressions.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ColumnResolutionHelper.$init$(ColumnResolutionHelper.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.<init>(Analyzer.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$build$2(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataset(SparkSession.scala:517)
    at com.comarch.Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:56)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseLexer.<clinit>(SqlBaseLexer.java:1834)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 4).
    ... 30 more
```

When I analyze dependencies in IntelliJ I can see "antlr4-runtime:4.10.1" beeing used by "spark-sql_2.13:3.5.0", but when I click on it and press "Go to Maven Dependency" it shows spark-sql POM using version 4.9.3.

[image]

Why is version 4.10.1 downloaded when it seems that Spark is using 4.9.3? Is it causing my problem, and of course how could I fix it?

I've tried removing ANTLR from m2 local repo, invalidating the cache a couple of times, but still, version 4.10.1 is downloaded when I reload maven project, and then this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies have dependency to ANTLR library with version 4.10.1.
So, maven takes the latest version during resolving, that is why you have 4.10.1 instead of your version 4.9.3.

Try to run command `mvn dependency:tree` to find the dependency that brings ANTLR:4.10.1 transitively.

Then, you can exclude transitive dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
           <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
              <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
              <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

[Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) you can find more details.

Comment: I excluded antlr4-runtime under spark-sql in my POM and now im getting: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/ParseCancellationException"

Question is why is even version 4.10.1 downloaded when it seems that in POM spark-sql is using 4.9.3?

Comment: Could you share output for mvn dependency:tree?

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus 3.5.3 is using ANTLR 4.10.1 and that was the cause of conflict. I simply added ANTLR 4.9.3 dependency in my project POM and it works now.